# How do I re-order tabular data within rails so that the most recent data appears at the top?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table

**Here is currently how the table is created. At present the most recent activity is appearing on page 3/4 of results.**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <% if @events.any? %>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-unstyled">
              <h3 class="panel-title padding-left">Proshare Admin</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <table class="table proshare-table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Activity</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th class="th-last">Time</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <%= render @events %>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <%= will_paginate @events %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean most recent?

Comment: Why do you not simply use "order"?
@events.order(created_at: :desc)

Answer (score 0):

Order by most recent events in your controller when assigning `@events`.

```
def index
  @events = Event.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

Comment: This is currently the controller set up. I've tried to amend it to @events.order(created_at: :desc) but it seems to break. Can I add it as another '@events'?

class UserEventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = UserEvent.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 200)
  end
end

Comment: `@events.order(created_at: :desc)` won't modify the original `@events` object. You'd have to reassign it to a new object, after calling `order`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you mean to display the recent events. It should be done in the EventsController.

```
def index
  @events = Event.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```